# Hibernate embed only some fields of the class (not an entire class)

Tags: java, hibernate

In my database, I have a table `Article` with 10 columns. I also have a table `Item` that has an `Article` as a foreign key - one of the fields in `Item` is the `Article_ID` field. However, the `Item` also has another field from the `Article`, and that is the `Article_Price`.

So the situation is that I have the field `Article_Price` both in my `Article` and `Item` table, even though the `Item` already has the `Article` as a FK.

The question is - how to embed **only** the `Article_Price` field in my `Item` class, and not the entire `Article` (since it already exists as a separate table)?

I understand that for embedding the whole `Article`, the code would look something like the following.

```
@Entity
@Embeddable
public class Article {
    //...


@Entity
public class Item {
    
    @Embedded
    Article article;
```

But I need only the `Article_Price` to be embedded, and the `Article` to remain as the FK. Something like this:

***Item.java***

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Item")
public class Item {
    
    @Id     
    @Column(name = "Item_ID", nullable = false)
    private int id;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "Article_ID")
    private Article article;

    @Embedded // I want only this attribute from Article to embedded here
    @Column(name = "Article_Price")
    private float articlePrice;
```

***Article.java***

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "Article")
public class Article {
    
    @Id
    private int id;

    @Embeddable // I want only this attribute to be embeddable
    @Column(name = "Article_Price", nullable = false)
    private float price;
```

How can I achieve this?

### UPDATE

I did the attribute override in my `Item.java` like this:

```
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "Article_ID", nullable = false)
    @Embedded // embedding only the price field
    @AttributeOverride(name = "price", column = @Column(name = "Article_Price", nullable = false))
    private Article article;
```

I am now able to store such `Item` object to the DB, and it maps to the correct `Article_ID` but the `Article_Price` field is always 0. So it doesn't copy the actual `Article_Price` from the `Article` table, but just defaults it. Any idea how to solve this?

I am saving like this:

```
    Session s = sf.openSession();
//      
//      // saving to the DB
        s.beginTransaction();

        Article article = s.get(Article.class, 5391); // 5391 is the ID
        Item item = new Item(6.00f, article, 18.00f);
        
        s.save(item);
```

The problem is that the `Article` with the ID 5391 has the `Article_Price` property value of 150, and when I save the `Item` with referenced this `Article`, in the `Item`'s property `Article_Price` it has the value of 0. It should also be 150.

Comment: That doesn't make much sense. Either Article is Embeddable, or it's an Entity.Either the article in Item is a ManyToOne, or it's embedded.  It can't be both. And if an Item has an Article, and an Article has a price, there is no point in having the article price duplicated in Item. Just remove that field/column from Item, and get the article price from the article of the item.

Comment: @JBNizet The Article is an entity in that it has it's own table in the database. However, the Item table has the column "Article_Price" which should have the same value as the "Article_Price" in the Article table itself. So I need to embed that "Article_Price" from the Article into the Item. I know it is strange database design, but I am just using the database, I can't redesign it, it is not mine.

Comment: I understand that, and it's precisely the problem. There is no reason to have two columns holding exactly the same thing. Just remove the price from Item. And if you can't for legacy reasons, then add a float price property in Item, and accept that you will need to maintain the two prices in coherence.